# FireBug/Safari Dev Tools: Locate JavaScript Operation

Tags: javascript, firebug

I'm using both FireBug and Safari Developer Tools to debug my javascript.

I'm curious if there is a method (using these tools, or others), to select a DOM element, and identify any javascript operating upon said element?

This would be hugely helpful in furthering my understanding of the plugins I use, by being able to locate specific operations and understand how they function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Safari/Chrome debuggers allow you to see event listeners associated with any DOM object.  I'm not aware of any tools to show you which javascript changes a given object.

Comment: Event Listeners should do the job. Care to give me a brief explanation of how to use Safari to do that?

Comment: If you go into the Elements tab in the Safari debugger, there's a panel on the right hand side for Event Listeners.  You select the desired object in the DOM on the left, expand the Event Listeners tab and see what is configured.